# Type definition file for @lokijs/loki (v2)?

Tags: typescript-typings, typescript2.0, lokijs

I realize this is still in beta, but are there typings available? I've got the beta code working, but would love to have a definition file to help me learn.  Is there guidance on getting it to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Check this out https://www.github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/lokijs

Comment: Thanks, but that's for v1.5.  I'm working with the beta of v2.